# MYSQL OR query problem (scans full table even when using indexes)

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am using EXPLAIN to get performance analysis of my below query:

```
SELECT `wf_cart_items` . `id`
FROM `wf_cart_items`
WHERE (`wf_cart_items` . `docket_number` = '405-2844' OR
       match( `wf_cart_items` . `multi_docket_number` ) against ( '405-2844' )
      )
```

[image]

The problem is that it shows rows to be searched 597151 while individual OR queries examine only 1 row each. How is it possible that when I use OR it is doing a full table scan?

[image: d]

[image]

P.S.: I have FULL-TEXT index on multi_docket_number & BTREE index on docket_number

Comment: Divide your query to 2 separate queries one condition each combined with UNION. *How is it possible that when I use OR it is doing a full table scan?* I think that optimiser cannot predict FTS selectivity, and it decides that tablescan may be more safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` is quite tricky for SQL optimizers -- both in the `WHERE` clause and in `ON` clauses.

The recommendation is to switch this to `union all`:

```
SELECT ci.id
FROM wf_cart_items ci
WHERE ci.docket_number = '405-2844' 
UNION ALL
SELECT ci.id
FROM wf_cart_items ci
WHERE MATCH(ci.multi_docket_number) AGAINST ( '405-2844' ) AND
      ci.docket_number <> '405-2844';
```

Based on the naming of your columns, I feat that `multi-docket_number` actually contains multiple docket numbers.  If that is the case, you probably want to fix the data model, but that is another conversation.